# Want to Get Sum of Time Field

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have Over Time field in data table containing data of different employees like 12:75 (12 hours AND 75 minutes) while i want it like 13:15 minutes. I want to get sum of total over time hours. How can i get result like this in VB.NET 2010. Please Help

Comment: Are you sure it's not 12,75 which would mean 12h45m? What's the type of OverTime property?

Comment: it is like 12:75 mean 12 h and 75 min but it should show like 13:15. 75 is minutes which have to be break on 60 mean 1 hour this hour will add in 12 so it will show 13:15 (13 h 15 m). it is a string field in database.

Comment: Sounds like you need two fields to hold the two separate values. Combining different data in the same field breaks the 1st Normal Form and is a very ... troubling design

Comment: Problem is still a problem, your given method works just for 24 hrs day. when employee get over time of 50 hrs and 75 minutes then it should show 51 hrs and 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple. Take the minutes part and divide it by 60. The amount (without decimal part) is number of hours and you add it to the number of hours. The decimal part you multiply by 60 and these are your minutes.

To code it in VB, we would need to know the type of OverTime property, but I also think you should write this code yourself as it is pretty straightforward. You can come back when you have a specific problem.

Comment: THanks Michal you have provided right idea to manage this task. I am thankfull to you.

Comment: Problem is still a problem, your given method works just for 24 hrs day. when employee get over time of 50 hrs and 75 minutes then it should show 51 hrs and 15 minutes.

Comment: That is not possible. It will work with any number of hours and minutes, unless you also want to work with days. But you only mentioned hours and minutes. Post your code, so we can see what the problem is.

Comment: I used timespan(12,75,0) idea. I used Dim ts as new Timespan(21,75,0) and call to check it in message box e.g. msgbox(ts.hour & ":" & ts.minutes) it is giving 22:15 which is right. But if i give it Timespan(25,75,0) then its return 2:15 ? while it has to show 26:15.  Remember i need to calculate all employees over time on date range i have field varchar 5 in sql table where all data exists like 00:00 (hrs, mins)

Comment: But, how am I supposed to know what you use? Check the `TimeSpan` documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx and you will find out about `.TotalMinutes`, those you can use the way I mentioned before...Post your code, that always helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 DateTime.AddMinutes
```

function where you will specify 75 and it will give you correct time.

or you can use

```
 var ts = new TimeSpan(12, 75, 0);//h,m,s
```

the sample piece of code would be,

```
        var ts = new TimeSpan(25, 75, 0);
        var total = ts.Days*24 + ts.Hours + ":" + ts.Minutes;
```

Comment: Can u please describe what is 0 on start and 0 on end?

Comment: its just day part, actually if you look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx , first argument is day part.  Well I just look at documentation and found that I don't have to provide that day part.

Comment: Problem is still a problem, your given method works just for 24 hrs day. when employee get over time of 50 hrs and 75 minutes then it should show 51 hrs and 15 minutes.

Comment: I used your give timespan(12,75,0) idea. I used Dim ts as new Timespan(21,75,0) and call to check it in message box e.g. msgbox(ts.hour & ":" & ts.minutes) it is giving 22:15 which is right. But if i give it Timespan(25,75,0) then its return 2:15 ? while it has to show 26:15.

Comment: it is correctly showing that, it must be showing day = 1, h = 2, m = something. so do 24 * timespan.day + timespan.hours + timespan.minutes

Comment: You mean like this? Dim ts As New TimeSpan(25, 75, 0)
            Dim abc = "24" * ts.Days + ts.Hours + ts.Minutes
            MsgBox(abc). it has to show 26:15 minute but it is showing 41  ? what is that? please explain

Comment: dear i dont want day in it i want everything in hours and minutes , please do , i m following u.

Comment: mate, you don't want date thus I said you need multiply the days resulted from timespan. I updated the answer which might help u, returns exactly what you want

Comment: Yes it is fine and superb, I applied and it works, i have verified all the data. showing fine. thank you very much. You pulled me out from the dark.